# Jquery Ui resizable custom handlers not working

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I am facing an issue I have a div that i wanna be resizing using custom handles.

```
handles: {
        'nw': '.tl',
        'ne': '.tr',
        'sw': '.bl',
        'se': '.br',
        'e': '.r',
        'w': '.l'
    }
```

so I set the class for every direction. But when I execute the nw,w and sw can't resize from the left, in fact they act as if they are new e and se.
Here is a live code to understand more.

http://jsfiddle.net/zhgouqc3/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to review the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cdLn56f1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="vidsub" style="position: relative; width: 417px; height: 53px; margin: 10px;background: red; z-index: 100;">
  sdsds
  <div class="l ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w resizable-wrapper" id="w"></div>
  <div class="r ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e resizable-wrapper" id="e"></div>
  <div class="tl ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nw"></div>
  <div class="tr ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="ne"></div>
  <div class="bl ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="sw"></div>
  <div class="br ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="se"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-resizable-handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 106);
  border-width: 1.5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-image: initial;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.resizable-wrapper {
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
}

.l {
  left: -4px;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.r {
  right: -4px;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.tl {
  left: -6px;
  top: -6px;
}

.tr {
  right: -6px;
  top: -6px;
}

.bl {
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
}

.br {
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#vidsub').resizable({
      handles: {
        'nw': '.tl',
        'ne': '.tr',
        'sw': '.bl',
        'se': '.br',
        'e': '.r',
        'w': '.l'
      }
  });
});
```

Please review the Docs:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

> Note: When generating your own handles, each handle must have the `ui-resizable-handle` class, as well as the appropriate `ui-resizable-{direction}` class, .e.g., `ui-resizable-s`.

So you have to adjust your Classes to fit the needs for handles. This will handle a lot of the cursors and CSS. Also your Fiddle was not setup correctly, corrected that.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Now it's much clearer to me :)